# Can't Append objects with armatures from Asset Library

Tags: armature, append, asset, library

Using the Asset library, I drag simple objects into my scene using the append option at the top of Asset library window, it works fine, can edit and such. But recently started to create objects with armatures, put some into the asset library, and when I wanted to drag them into my other blend file, they behave like linked objects. Can't edit or anything. (Still with Append option selected) Tried to make them local (With "Ctr+L" and such, but no luck. Am I doing something wrong? Or shall i report it as a bug? Or is there a workaround ?

Thank you very much!